# Fix \hookrightarrow in kpfonts

Tags: arrows, kpfonts

The `\hookrightarrow` in `kpfonts` looks like this:

[image]

I assume this is an error. What can I do to fix this? I would like to keep using `kpfonts`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
    \Huge $\hookrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You ask Christophe Caignaert to fix the font.

Comment: Sounds like a rather long-term fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the report!

I identify the bug's source an it will be fixed as soon as possible!

Christophe Caignaert

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: But you are the author of `kpfonts`... I guess this is a kind of answer??

Comment: Perhaps we should get you started on TeX.SE by accepting this answer. I assume @egreg won't mind, given the fact that he currently has a score of 364k.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! And thanks for your nice set of fonts! Is there any hope for an OpenType version of them? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler I'm mortally outraged by your choice of switching the tick. `;-D`

Comment: Again thank you for your quick fix, @egreg, it works extraordinarily. `:-D`

Answer (score 5):

The hook is completely wrong: its thickness is larger than the arrow shaft's and it is positioned too high.

The font should be fixed by its author. In the meantime you can arrange it by yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\let\kp@lhook\lhook
\renewcommand{\lhook}{\mathrel{\text{\fix@lhook}}}
\newcommand\fix@lhook{%
  \raisebox{.045ex}{%
    \scalebox{.85}{$\m@th\kp@lhook$}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\hookrightarrow$

\Huge $\hookrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]