# strange extensible arrows with kpfonts

Tags: amsmath, arrows, mathtools, kpfonts, xrightarrow

The extensible arrows from `amsmath`/`mathtools` do not give proper spacing or symbols when used with `kpfonts`. Here's the correct behavior with Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    X &\rightarrow Y & X &\hookrightarrow Y & X &\mapsto Y \\
    X &\xrightarrow{} Y & X &\xhookrightarrow{} Y & X &\xmapsto{} Y
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: correct_computer-modern]

The spacing and symbols of the extensible arrows with no label are identical to their non-extensible counterparts, as expected.

When `kpfonts` is loaded, the spacing and symbols change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,kpfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    X &\rightarrow Y & X &\hookrightarrow Y & X &\mapsto Y \\
    X &\xrightarrow{} Y & X &\xhookrightarrow{} Y & X &\xmapsto{} Y
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: incorrect_kpfonts]

All three arrows appear to shift to the left, which causes both the hook in `\xhookrightarrow` and the vertical bar in `\xmapsto` to be in the wrong spot.

Note also that `\hookrightarrow` looks bad to begin with. Not sure if this is new, or if [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233608/208544) was never fixed.

Why is this happening, and is it an issue I should report to `mathtools` or to `kpfonts`?

Comment: The issue appears never to have been fixed, even though he sent a preliminary update to me which I was using for some years. The `kpfonts` package has received updates on CTAN several times since, so I assume that the developer must have simply forgotten about it.

Comment: @Gaussler From the [change log](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/kpfonts/Changes) it seems Herbert Voß is the new maintainer? Perhaps the fix for `\hookrightarrow` could be sent to him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `amsmath` makes a few assumptions on the math symbols, which don't hold for `kpfonts`;
2. the `\lhook` symbol in `kpfonts` is badly designed.

For problem 1 we can patch `\arrow@fill` to reduce the negative kerns at either end. For problem 2, we can borrow the `\lhook` symbol from `libertinust1math`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,kpfonts}

\makeatletter % change \mkern-7mu into \mkern-4mu
\def\arrowfill@#1#2#3#4{%
  $\m@th\thickmuskip0mu\medmuskip\thickmuskip\thinmuskip\thickmuskip
   \relax#4#1\mkern-4mu%
   \cleaders\hbox{$#4\mkern-2mu#2\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
   \mkern-4mu#3$%
}
\makeatother

%%% borrow \lhook and \rhook from libertinust1math
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{libertinust1mathex}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{libsymbols}{LS2}{libertinust1mathsym}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lhook}{\mathrel}{libsymbols}{"41}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rhook}{\mathrel}{libsymbols}{"42}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  X &\rightarrow Y &\quad X &\hookrightarrow Y & X &\mapsto Y \\
  X &\xrightarrow{} Y & X &\xhookrightarrow{} Y & X &\xmapsto{} Y
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
X\xrightarrow{abcde}
X\xhookrightarrow{abcde}
X\xmapsto{abcde} X
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Of course, `\xrightarrow{}` and the other arrows will not be as wide as the nonextensible companions. I don't think one can do much about this, apart from using the `x` arrows only when needed.

[image]